# Cloudformation DynamoDB Failure to Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have this template, all very simple.

```yaml
DepartmentsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: "Departments"
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - 
        AttributeName: "id"
        AttributeType: "S" 
      -
        AttributeName: "client_id"
        AttributeType: "S"
      -
        AttributeName: "department_name"
        AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema:
      - 
        AttributeName: "id"
        KeyType: "HASH"
    BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
```

When I deploy with 3 attributeNames, it wont deploy.

When I change the template to have a single attribute, it does deploy.

Any ideas

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is schemaless, so in that regard you must only define the keys you require at creation time.

As you use only `id` as your hash key, that must be the only attribute you define, you are free to add `client_id` and `department_name` to your items when you insert them, there is no requirement for CFN to know about these. This is why you get the exception.

```
DepartmentsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: "Departments"
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - 
        AttributeName: "id"
        AttributeType: "S" 
    KeySchema:
      - 
        AttributeName: "id"
        KeyType: "HASH"
    BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
```

Update:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table 
    Properties: 
      TableName: Departments 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: id 
          AttributeType: S 
        - AttributeName: sortKey 
          AttributeType: S 
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: id 
          KeyType: HASH 
        - AttributeName: sortKey 
          KeyType: RANGE 
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: You must also define attributes for table indexes. From AWS Doc ```AttributeDefinitions:
A list of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and indexes.```

Comment: I am still gettiing nowhwere with this as soon as I add a second attribute, e.g. a sort key, the deployment fails.  DepartmentsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: Departments
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: sortKey
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: sortKey
          KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1

Comment: Edited my answer. In future, don't say something "fails". Its better to say, I tried this, it failed with this exception: `some exception`